# How can I select the record with the 2nd highest salary in database Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table employee with id, user_name, salary. How can I select the record with the 2nd highest salary in Oracle?

I googled it, find this solution, is the following right?:

```
select sal from
     (select rownum n,a.* from
        ( select distinct sal from emp order by sal desc) a)
where n = 2;
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

RANK and DENSE_RANK have already been suggested - depending on your requirements, you might also consider ROW_NUMBER():

```
select * from (
  select e.*, row_number() over (order by sal desc) rn from emp e
)
where rn = 2;
```

The difference between RANK(), DENSE_RANK() and ROW_NUMBER() boils down to:

- ROW_NUMBER() always generates a unique ranking; if the ORDER BY clause cannot distinguish between two rows, it will still give them different rankings (randomly)
- RANK() and DENSE_RANK() will give the same ranking to rows that cannot be distinguished by the ORDER BY clause
- DENSE_RANK() will always generate a contiguous sequence of ranks (1,2,3,...), whereas RANK() will leave gaps after two or more rows with the same rank (think "Olympic Games": if two athletes win the gold medal, there is no second place, only third)

So, if you only want one employee (even if there are several with the 2nd highest salary), I'd recommend ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: +1 to Gave a good understanding between RANK and DENSE_RANK with 'Olymic games' example.

Comment: Above row_number() function query will give wrong result if two employees have the same highest salary. We can you dense_rank() analytic function to get desired result.

Comment: @TarunKumar As I had mentioned in my answer - depending on your requirements, you need either `rank / dense_rank` to get all employees with the highest salary or `row_number` if you want to ensure that you always get exactly one record.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Oracle 8+, you can use the `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` functions like so

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT some_column, 
         rank() over (order by your_sort_column desc) as row_rank
) t
WHERE row_rank = 2;
```

Comment: I mistyped 9, meant 8, it's been corrected. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: NB This query can return more than one row while the query posted in the question which will return the does a distinct to filter duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

This query works in **SQL*PLUS** to find out the **2nd Highest Salary** -

```
SELECT * FROM EMP
WHERE SAL = (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP
WHERE SAL < (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP));
```

This is **double sub-query**.

I hope this helps you..

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  id, user_name, salary,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY salary DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT  id, user_name, salary
FROM    records 
WHERE   rn = 2
```

- [DENSE_RANK()](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php)

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select salary2.*, rownum rnum from
         (select * from salary ORDER BY salary_amount DESC) salary2
  where rownum <= 2 )
WHERE rnum >= 2;
```

Comment: Why do I have to use it as "rnum<=2" and "rnum>=2", can't I just say "rnum=2"?

Comment: @user1801838 No. You cannot use rownum with = n for n > 1 (in fact you can, but it will always return an empty result set).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from emp where sal=(select max(sal) from emp where sal<(select max(sal) from emp))
```

so in our emp table(default provided by oracle) here is the output

EMPNO ENAME      JOB           MGR HIREDATE     SAL       COMM     DEPTNO

---

```
  7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       3000            30
  7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000            20
  7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000            20
```

or just you want 2nd maximum salary to be displayed

```
select max(sal) from emp where sal<(select max(sal) from emp)
```

### MAX(SAL)

```
  3000
```

Comment: please learn to use the format tags and use them to make the answers readable :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
select * FROM (
select EmployeeID, Salary
, dense_rank() over (order by Salary DESC) ranking
from Employee
)
WHERE ranking = 2;
```

**dense_rank()** is used for the salary has to be same.So it give the proper output instead of using **rank()**.

Answer (score 1):

select Max(Salary) as SecondHighestSalary from Employee where Salary not in 
(select max(Salary) from Employee)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will accomplish the same result, without a subquery or a ranking function:

```
SELECT *
FROM emp
ORDER BY sal DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 2
```

Comment: FYI, LIMIT keyword is not available on Oracle database, secondly, it would give wrong result if two employees have the same highest salary. We can you dense_rank() analytic function to get desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This query helps me every time for problems like this. Replace N with position..

```
select *
from(
     select *
     from (select * from TABLE_NAME order by SALARY_COLUMN desc)
     where rownum <=N
    )
where SALARY_COLUMN <= all(
                select SALARY_COLUMN
                from (select * from TABLE_NAME order by SALARY_COLUMN desc)
                where rownum <=N
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from emp where sal = (
select sal from
     (select rownum n,a.sal from
    ( select distinct sal from emp order by sal desc) a)
where n = 2);
```

This is more optimum, it suits all scenarios...

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(Salary) from EmployeeTest where Salary < ( select max(Salary) from EmployeeTest ) ;
```

this will work for all DBs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following two ways to implement this in Oracle.

1. Using Sub-query:

```sql
select distinct SALARY   
from EMPLOYEE e1  
where 1=(select count(DISTINCT e2.SALARY) from EMPLOYEE e2 where         
  e2.SALARY>e1.SALARY);
```

This is very simple query to get required output. However, this query is quite slow as each salary in inner query is compared with all distinct salaries.

2. Using DENSE_RANK():

```sql
select distinct SALARY   
from
  (
    select e1.*, DENSE_RANK () OVER (order by SALARY desc) as RN 
    from EMPLOYEE e
  ) E
 where E.RN=2;
```

This is very efficient query. It works well with DENSE_RANK() which assigns consecutive ranks unlike RANK() which assigns next rank depending on row number which is like olympic medaling.

Difference between RANK() and DENSE_RANK():
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use two max function. Let's say get data of userid=10 and its 2nd highest salary from SALARY_TBL.

```
select max(salary) from SALARY_TBL
where 
userid=10
salary <> (select max(salary) from SALARY_TBL where userid=10)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Replace N with your Highest Number**

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2
WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

Explanation

The query above can be quite confusing if you have not seen anything like it before – the inner query is what’s called a correlated sub-query because the inner query (the subquery) uses a value from the outer query (in this case the Emp1 table) in it’s WHERE clause.

And **[Source](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/)**

**[I have given the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234983/how-to-find-third-or-nth-maximum-salary-from-salary-table/16235042#16235042)**

By the way I am flagging this Question as **Duplicate.**

Comment: -1. 361 consistent gets for a sample `hr.employees` table with 107 rows.

Comment: there is no error, your approach is dramatically suboptimal from performance point of view. for instance @hd1's query reads only 6 blocks

Answer (score -1):

Syntax it for Sql server

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) as 'Salary' from EmployeeDetails
where Salary NOT IN
(
SELECT TOP n-1 (SALARY) from EmployeeDetails ORDER BY Salary Desc
)
```

To get **2nd highest salary of employee** then we need replace “n” with 2 our query like will be this

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) as 'Salary' from EmployeeDetails
where Salary NOT IN
(
SELECT TOP 1 (SALARY) from EmployeeDetails ORDER BY Salary Desc
)
```

**3rd highest salary of employee**

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) as 'Salary' from EmployeeDetails
where Salary NOT IN
(
SELECT TOP 2 (SALARY) from EmployeeDetails ORDER BY Salary Desc
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE SAL=(SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP WHERE SAL<(SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM  EMP));
```

(OR)

```
SELECT ENAME ,SAL  FROM EMP  ORDER BY SAL DESC;
```

(OR)

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT ENAME,SAL ,DENSE_RANK() 
OVER(PARTITION BY DEPTNO ORDER BY SAL DESC) R FROM EMP) WHERE R=2;
```

Comment: Please augment this code-only answer with some explanation.

Comment: You chose to undo a helpful edit, which demonstrated less ambiguos formatting. Now try yourself to fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Answer (score -2):

```
select salary from EmployeeDetails order by salary desc limit 1 offset (n-1).
```

If you want to find 2nd highest than replace `n` with that `2`.