# SQL - Select name of the person with highest salary

Tags: sql, select, max

I have a table called workers which includes a few persons by their names, their salary and their working station. The table looks something like the following:

```
|Name|Station|Salary|
|Kyle|1      |2200  |
|Lisa|2      |2250  |
|Mark|3      |1800  |
|Hans|4      |1350  |
```

This might sound like a very obvious beginner question but I cannot get it work. I would like to select the name of the person with the highest salary. Thank you for reading, and have a nice one.

Comment: do you want to include ties. If kyle and lisa both have 2250 salary should you list both of them?

Comment: Check this out: [How to find third or nᵗʰ maximum salary from salary table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833322/10204932)

Answer (score 6):

```
Select name 
from table 
where salary = (select max(salary) from table)
```

I dont know if you want to include ties or not (if two people have the same salary and it is the max salary.

What this does is find the max salary and then uses that in the query to find all people with that salary. You will need to replace the word table with whatever your table name is.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT top 1 Name
FROM tableName
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Comment: this will not work for ties, I dont know if op needs ties to work, but if there are ties this will drop all the results.

Comment: no it will not. You are selecting the first name ordering by salary descending. IF there is a tie it will not return the second person. It will only return the first result, not the second. The second result would be the tie. Try it in sqlfiddle

Comment: create table foobar(
  name varchar(20) null,
  salary int)

insert into foobar
select 'test',300

insert into foobar
select 'fail', 300

select top 1 * from foobar order by salary

<b>run it and see. it doesnt work for ties</b>

Comment: My answer is correct as per the question, question says only name not names and hence no ties are required. :)

Comment: too true, just letting you know it wont work for ties.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention DBMS:

```
select name 
from table
order by salary desc
fetch first 1 rows only
```

If your DBMS support OLAP functions:

```
select name from (
    select name, row_number() over (order by salary desc) as rn 
    from table
) where rn = 1
```

Comment: since op didnt mentiond DBMS i went with an ansi sql solution.

Comment: Both of mine are as well, not sure if fetch first where introduced in SQL2008 or SQL2011, row_number() has been around since SQL99

Comment: both of your answers are not ansi sql, and there is nothing wrong with that. I am just letting op know. The second one uses TSQL row_number over. And Fetch is a keyword in sql server indicating the use of a cursor. So the first one wont run on sql server and the second one will only run on sql server. My answer will run on any DBMS system.

Comment: Are you suggesting that whether the statements work or not in sqlserver has anything to do with whether they are iso/ansi compliant or not? row_number() over ( ... ) is for example described in chapter 6.10 <window function> in SQL2003. You can download draft documents from http://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html and verify. As for fetch first I cant seem to find a reference for that one so I'll withdraw that. If I find it I'll post back

Comment: I cant find fetch first in the documents right now, but it is described in this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28SQL%29 . Look for FETCH FIRST clause. It is btw supported by SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
SELECT TOP name 
FROM yourtable 
WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM yourtable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use subquery to get name and highest salary:

```
select Name, Salary from tb_name where salary=(select max(salary) from tb_name);
```