# SQL Server 2008 R2: Find a second largest number in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following table with some data to find second largest number.

Table:

```
ColA
---------
3
23
43
673
173
373
273
```

Comment: What if the biggest number is twice in the table?

Comment: @Amit A simple question doesn't indicate homework/course. However , regarding self effort - I agree.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - So why do you answer such a question? You shouldn't encourage others to ask such questions by rewarding them with answers, you should de-motivate. Downvote.

Comment: @Amit He asks a question. If he wants other people to solve his exercises without learning - that's his problem. He will lose from it . not me. I will be a better programmer since I solved one more drill. My downvote won't help anyone here. I would've downvote if the question was purely written , unclear etc. _de-motivate_  ( as you said) never helped anyone , nor will.

Comment: Most of the answers from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234983/how-to-find-third-or-nth-maximum-salary-from-salary-table return wrong results when the same salary exists multiple times, e.g. 10,20,30,30 -> 2nd highest is 20, not 30. Instead of ROW_NUMBER one must use DENSE_RANK instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Use this:</strike>

```
select * from 
(select colA  , row_number() over(order by colA desc) as rn from Table) T
where T.rn=2
```

Thanks to Martin's / dnoeth's comment :

It can be problematic with 2 max inetegers

Use this :

```
  select * from 
    (select colA  , DENSE_RANK( ) OVER (ORDER BY colA  ) as rn from Table) T
    where T.rn=2
```

**Additional info** : (once and for all  ( *learn it!*  , I always use it)) :

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(NAME NVARCHAR(MAX),val money)

insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'a',100
insert INTO @t SELECT 'b',200
insert INTO @t SELECT 'b',200
insert INTO @t SELECT 'd',400
insert INTO @t SELECT 'e',500
insert INTO @t SELECT 'f',600
select  Name,
        val,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME  ORDER BY name),
        val/ SUM(val) OVER(PARTITION BY NAME )  AS '1AgainstTotalHimself',
        val/ SUM(val) OVER( )  AS '1AgainstOthers' , 
        NTILE(2) OVER ( PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY name) AS 'ntile2' ,
        NTILE(2) OVER ( ORDER BY name) AS 'ntile' , -- ( 9%2=1  , so group #1 will get more number) 
        RANK( ) OVER ( ORDER BY name  ) AS  Rank,
        DENSE_RANK( ) OVER (ORDER BY name) AS DENSERANK

from @t
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: Switch to DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER to get the correct result when multiple rows share the same salary.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks. indeed you and martin are right !

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this would be

```
with cte as (
    select ColA, 
           Row_number() over(order by ColA DESC) As rn
    FROM Table
)

SELECT ColA
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 2
```

**Update**
After Martin's correct comment, here is a better answer:

```
Select top 1 ColA
From YourTable
WHERE ColA < (
   SELECT MAX(ColA) 
   FROM YourTable
)
ORDER BY ColA DESC
```

Comment: This might find the largest number if it appears twice.

Comment: Or simply use DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER

Comment: @MartinSmith I start thinking  , my solution can also yield wrong result.

Comment: @RoyiNamir yep. I thought one comment making the point was sufficient though rather than spamming all answers.