# 3rd highest salary sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, highest

I try to get all 3 highest salary from top 5 employees like this

```
    salary
  35000
  34000
  20000
  12000
  500
  40000
  25000
  41000
  90000
  550000
```

query

```
select top 5
  (SELECT MAX(grosssalary) FROM Detail) maxsalary ,
   (SELECT MAX(grosssalary) FROM Detail) sec_max_salary,
  (SELECT MAX(grosssalary) FROM Detail
  WHERE grosssalary NOT IN (SELECT MAX(grosssalary) FROM Detail )) as third_max_salary
```

but this shows data like this

```
maxsalary   sec_max_salary  third_max_salary
550000       550000            41000
```

where as i want data like this

```
   maxsalary    sec_max_salary  third_max_salary
    550000       90000            41000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234983/how-to-find-third-or-nth-maximum-salary-from-salary-table

Comment: can u check my answer @superuser

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16234983/3261852

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `CTE` and get the `ROWNUMBER()` on `salary DESC` and in outer query fetch the record with rownumber equal to 3.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC),
           Salary
     FROM [YourTable]
 )

 SELECT Salary
 FROM CTE
 WHERE RN <= 3
```

**Note:** If you want 3rd highest salary use `RN=3` if you want all top 3 salary then use `RN<=3`

If you want top 3 highest salary then you can do this as well:

```
SELECT TOP 3 Salary
FROM [YourTable]
ORDER BY Salary DESC
```

Comment: what is CTE? and this is complicated query please modify according t my query

Comment: @superuser this will give you the top 3 salaries but they could still all be the same salary.  If you are looking for the top 3 different salaries then all you would need to do is switch ROW_NUMBER() to DENSE_RANK().  Also note using PIVOT with this out put will get you to 3 columns instead of rows nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
 CREATE TABLE #A
 (

 salary INT
 )
 INSERT INTO #A VALUES
  (35000),
  (34000),
  (20000),
  (12000),
  (500  ),
  (40000),
  (25000),
  (41000),
  (90000),
  (550000)


select [1] maxsalary, [2] sec_max_salary, [3] third_max_salary
from (
SELECT *
FROM (

    SELECT *,
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC)
    FROM #A
)a
WHERE RN  <= 3

) src
pivot
(
  MAX(SALARY)
  for RN in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv;
```

OUTPUT

```
maxsalary   sec_max_salary  third_max_salary
550000       90000           41000
```

Answer (score 1):

Table Name:-ThreeHighestSalaries

### name -------- Salary

- e5   -------- 45000
- e3   -------- 30000
- e2   -------- 49000
- e4   -------- 36600
- e1   -------- 58000
- e6   -------- 58000

Should return 58000,49000,45000.

1)select *,dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) as salaryrank from ThreeHighestSalaries

The above query returns:

### Name --------- Salary------Rank

- e1 --------- 58000 --------- 1
- e6 --------- 58000 --------- 1
- e2 --------- 49000 --------- 2
- e5 --------- 45000 --------- 3
- e4 --------- 36600 --------- 4
- e3 --------- 30000 --------- 5

2)select distinct salary from (select *,dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) as salaryrank from ThreeHighestSalaries) as temp where temp.salaryrank<=3 order by salary desc

The above query returns result as:

### Salary

- 58000
- 49000
- 45000

Answer (score 0):

Use `DENSE_RANK()` to order the salary and then use a `CASE` expression to find the top 3 salaries.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [sal_rank] = dense_rank() over(
        order by [grosssalary] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select max(case [sal_rank] when 1 then [grosssalary] end) as [maxsalary],
max(case [sal_rank] when 2 then [grosssalary] end) as [sec_max_salary],
max(case [sal_rank] when 3 then [grosssalary] end) as [third_max_salary]
from cte;
```

Comment: @superuser : [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: RANK() here could be problematic because if 2 people share the top salary it would rank 1 1 3 so you second max salary would be NULL.  If you want to allow for ties like this DENSE_RANK() would work better but the conditional aggregation is a good tip for the OP

Comment: @Matt : Yeah that's correct.. `DENSE_RANK` will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `SQL SERVER 2012+` then use `OFFSET`

```
SELECT TOP 1 salary,
             (SELECT salary FROM Yourtable
              ORDER  BY salary DESC OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY),
             (SELECT salary FROM Yourtable 
              ORDER  BY salary DESC OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
FROM   Yourtable
ORDER  BY salary DESC
```

If you want just the 3rd highest salary then

```
SELECT salary
FROM   yourtable
ORDER  BY salary DESC 
OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will Lead you to get N'th largest or Smallest salary values irrespective to Datatype ie. integer or Vearchar. 
just change the '<' sign for smaller n'th values.

```
select * from txt_salary as t1 where 'nth largest' =
(select count(salary) from txt_salary as t2 where t1.salary<=t2.salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

***For SQL SERVER***

SELECT e1.* FROM `emp` e1 WHERE e1.salary = 
(
select MIN(e2.salary)
from (select top 3 DISTINCT(e3.salary) from `emp` as e3 ORDER by e3.salary desc ) as e2
)

***For MYSQL***

SELECT e1.* FROM `emp` e1 WHERE e1.salary = 
(
select MIN(e2.salary)
from (select DISTINCT(e3.salary) from `emp` as e3 ORDER by e3.salary desc  limit 0,3) as e2
)

Answer (score 0):

select max(salary) as highest from employee
UNION
select max(salary) as 2nd_highest from employee where salary<(select max(salary) from employee)
UNION
max(salary) as 3rd_highest from employee where salary<(select max(salary) from employee where salary< (select max(salary) from employee))=

**For 18th highest salary=**
select salary, ename, eid FROM (select e.ename, e.salary, e.eid, rank() OVER (order by e.eid desc) rank) WHERE rank=18

Answer (score 0):

declare @tem1 table(salary int)

insert into @tem1(salary) select top 3 grosssalary from Detail order by grosssalary desc

select top 1 sal as 3rdsalary from @tem1 order by sal asc

Answer (score -2):

```
select * 
from 
( select *
  from table 
  order by salary desc
  limit 3 
) as top_three
order by top_three.salary asc
limit 1
```

Comment: sql-server uses SELECT TOP not limit