# How to select only the second result from a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server.
I have an SQL Query which returns more than one row and I need to select only the 2nd result from it or the first result may be.
What query should I write for this requirement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL How to select only Second row from a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617152/t-sql-how-to-select-only-second-row-from-a-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `offset`/`fetch`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by col
offset 1 fetch next 1 row only;
```

Notes:

- A SQL result set returns rows in an indeterminate order, unless you have an `order by`.  Even running the query twice on the same system and return the rows in different order, so you need the `order by`.
- The offsets start at 0 for the first row.  For the second row, `offset 1`.
- `offset`/`fetch` is ANSI standard syntax.

Comment: how do I fetch the second row?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN ASC LIMIT 1 
TO FETCH FIRST ROW

SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY COLUMN DESC LIMIT 1
TO FETCH LAST ROW

Answer (score 1):

We can use `TOP` clause for this -

```
SELECT TOP (1) Col1 FROM (Your SQL Query) as XYZ Order By Col3 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT r.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeField ASC) AS RowNum
) sorty
WHERE RowNum = 2
```

Comment: can I create an array and store more than one value in a single variable? My select statement was returning more than one value and I need to store it in a variable. How can I do that?

Comment: use `table` variable.