# t-sql query : retrieve latest row approaches

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Based on the following table

```
Table_A

ID   Rev  Description
-----------------------------------
1    1    Some text.
1    2    Some text. Adding more.
1    3    Some text. Ading more & more.
```

The above will keep adding a new row when user updates the description.

I want to take the row with MAX(Rev) [i.e. the latest description].

To get this I do the following:

```
;with AllDescriptions As
(
 select 
        ID
        , Rev
        , Description 
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by Rev desc) as RowNum
        from Table_A
        Where ID = 1
)
select ID, Rev, Description from AllDescription
where RowNum = 1
```

Recently I saw a different approach to getting the same result

```
select b.* from 
(
 select ID, MAX(Rev) as MaxRev 
 from Table_A 
 where ID = 1
 group by ID
) as a
inner join 
(
 select ID, Rev, Description from Table_A where ID = 1
) as b
on a.ID = b.ID and a.MaxRev = b.Rev
```

From learning perspective, I want to know Which of the above two approaches is better? Or if there is even better way to do the same?

Comment: Check the execution plans. Version 2 may exhibit some single-seek-plus-partition optimizer magic. I've seen this example before, don't remember where. *Inside SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming*, perhaps?

Comment: @Peter - I seem to recall that they did a comparison against either a JOIN or CROSS APPLY with `TOP 1` in those books I forget the details.

Comment: I've just tried both - `STATISTICS IO` gives almost identical numbers of reads for both options, with a supporting clustered index on the table.  The query plan figures that the ROW_NUMBER variant is much more expensive wrt. 'Query Cost Relative to Batch' - but I think this is misleading in this instance.

Comment: @Will I've quite lost faith in the `Query Cost Relative to Batch` figures since I found them to be so woefully wrong in this case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424650/sql-query-pervious-row-optimisation/3426364#3426364

Comment: @Martin - Likewise - they're always different from the actual cost in terms of CPU / IO.  It'd be nice to get a subset of the `STATISTICS IO` and `STATISTICS TIME` information shown instead here.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser I'd love to hear about performance results for the queries in my answer, if you feel like checking it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach looks like a SQL Server 2000 approach before `Row_Number()` was introduced. This is the [Greatest-n-per-group problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).

To evaluate them you should look at the execution plans and the I/O Stats by running `SET STATISTICS IO ON`

Of course for the specific example you have given the following would work equally well

```
 select TOP 1
        ID
        , Rev
        , Description 
        from Table_A
        Where ID = 1
ORDER BY Rev desc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parent table with each ID listed only once, this can sometimes outperform other strategies including the row_number solution:

```
SELECT
   X.*
FROM
   ParentTable P
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Table_A A
      WHERE P.ID = A.ID
      ORDER BY A.Rev DESC
   ) X
```

And the crazy, patented (just kidding), single scan magic query which can often outperform other methods as well:

```
SELECT
   ID,
   Rev = Convert(int, Substring(Packed, 1, 4)),
   Description = Convert(varchar(100), Substring(Packed, 5, 100))
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         ID,
         Packed = Max(Convert(binary(4), Rev) + Convert(varbinary(100), Description))
      FROM Table_A
      GROUP BY ID
   ) X
```

Note: this last method is not recommended, but it's fun to simulate the First/Last aggregates in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to favour the first approach - from a readability perspective, once you're comfortable with the ROW_NUMBER() OVER ... syntax then it's somewhat more readable.  From a performance perspective, I would be surprised if there was much difference between the two - if there is then I would expect that the second would perform worse - but I stand to be corrected on that!